# NuxtJS + axios GET not querying for parameters

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a table `resources` with severals records. I'm trying to build a form with a button so the user can query it, but I can't get the first piece to work, which is building a custom query with params. In the example, I tried to have it fetch only id = 1, but it returns all records and I don't know why.

```
  <ul>
    <li v-for="resource in resources">
      Facility: {{resource.facility}}
      Type: {{ resource.resource_type }}
      ID: {{ resource.id }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      resources: []
    }
  },

  fetch: async function() {
    this.resources = await this.$axios.$get('/resources/',
    {
      params: {
        id: 1, // this does not only filter facilities with this id
      }
    })
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Did you double-checked that your backend is working fine?

Comment: @kissu Yes, I did